# Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: ContentDocument

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, standard-objects, contentdocument, vs-code

I have made changes to the record page of content document object, now I need to push the record page to other org.
tried to retrieve the contentdocument object from vscode editor but receiving 
"Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: ContentDocument" message.

Answer (score 0):

Record pages are not stored as part of the `CustomObject` entity.

To retrieve Lightning Record Pages, retrieve the [`FlexiPage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) entity (along with any custom components used).

To retrieve Page Layouts, which dictate some elements of the Lightning Record Page (such as the content of standard Related Lists components), retrieve the [`Layout`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm) component.

In both cases, you'll want to retrieve based on the actual API names of the components you've edited.

Comment: Yes david but i need to add action overrides, in the object file. that is the reason why im retrieving the object file.